# What methods and properties are available in Java array like String[] strs?

Tags: java

I could not locate the package in which Java defines raw arrays like String[] strs
( not ArrayList).

What methods and properties are defined in such Java array and how do I return an iterator for such array supposed I am asked to return an iterator for two integers begin and end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a good summary:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html
>
> 10.7 Array Members
>
> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The public final field length, which contains the number of components of the array (length may be positive or zero)
> - The public method clone, which overrides the method of the same name in class Object and throws no checked exceptions
> - All the members inherited from class Object; the only method of Object that is not inherited is its clone method

As far as "iterators"; the "beginning" and "end" are simply "0" and ".length - 1".  You can always implement your own class that wraps an array and implements [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: The link is dead, I propose [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The only properties available (specific to Arrays) are really `.length`, and the index accessor, e.g. `[0]`.

Arrays can be used in the new for loop syntax provided with Java 1.5:

```
for(String s : new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}){
  // Something with s.
}
```

You can also access an Array as a List, using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29 .

Also see the rest of the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Arrays.html) class for many other operations that exist to operate specifically on arrays.  (Here, we have a class that operates *on* arrays, rather than the array containing all of the useful properties and methods.)

Comment: This is not quite right. Arrays also have all the methods `Object` has (`.equals()`, `.hashCode()`, `.toString()`, etc). That happens because arrays *are* objects (eg: `int[] arr = {1,2,3}; System.out.println(arr instanceof Object); // prints true`)

Comment: NullUserException - good catch.  I clarified my answer to include properties "specific to Arrays".

Comment: @NullUserException: true, but they don't have very useful implementations for arrays.